# Are there different ways of mathematically expressing probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading [this](http://www.cosbkup.gatech.edu/group/chem780/CHAPT1.pdf) PDF on the kinetic theory of gases when I encountered some probability maths I've been struggling to wrap my mind around (pages 1-7 through 1-10).

---

## Discrete Probability

Let's start by looking at two simple examples of discrete probability: rolling a 6 sided die and exam scores. I can use the following equation to calculate the average value for a series of dice rolls and for a series of exam scores:

$$<j>=\frac{1}{N_T}\sum_{j_{min}}^{j_{max}}j*N_j \tag{1}$$

where $j$ is a value a random variable can be, $N_T$
 is the total number of values the random variable can take on, and $N_j$ is the amount of times the random variable takes on the value of $j$.

Ex: If we rolled the dice 7 times and got values of $1,1,1,2,5,5,6,$ then the average value for those series of rolls would be 3 [using formula, (1*3+2*1+5*2+6*1)/7].

Now according to the chapter I'm reading (pg 1-8, eq 1-10): $$P_j=\frac{N_j}{N_T}\tag{2}$$

where $P_j$ is the probability of the random variable coming up with the value of $j$.

Here is where my first confusion arises. What does the term $N_j$ actually mean? Is it (like I said assumed above) the number of times the random variable DOES take on the value of $j$. **Or is it the number of times the random variable CAN be chosen to take on the value of $j$ each time the event occurs?** The distinction here is important because the "probability" of each dice side being rolled is the same each time the dice is rolled. But the "probability" of a student getting a score of 50 changes for each class!

If we assume the definition of $N_j$ to be latter, then Equation 2 is ONLY true when each value of $j$ can only be chosen the same amount of times every time the event occurs OR if the event has occurred an infinite amount of times.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than $<, >$ does :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused $<j>$ to be the value of the random variable, but its the expected value.

The whole issue of the discreet part (in the pdf you refer to) seems to be about constructing a distribution from observations. $N_T$ is the total number of observations and for some possible value $j$, $N_j$ is the number of observations with that value. Its a way to explain distributions through the context of [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).

**Edit:**

> The distinction here is important because the "probability" of each dice side being rolled is the same each time the dice is rolled. But the "probability" of a student getting a score of 50 changes for each class!

The distinction here (as well as in the follow-up comments) is that the dice rolls are perceived to be an identical repeat of the same "thing", while students taking a test is not. Like I wrote in the comments, if you have a pile of graded tests, then the act of taking one out of the pile is assumed to be repetitive identically.

Now, you actually **could** say - "the probability of getting 50 on test *Q* is 0.7", because out of $N_T$ students who took the test already $N_j=0.7\cdot N_T$ of them actually got 50 (the frequentist approach to probability), or because you believe that this is the probability of that event (the subjective probability approach) and then you expect that out of $N_T$ students who will take the test, $N_j$ will get 50.
(For dice rolls I would say that the probability is subjective, because i cant find any record of someone rolling every existing dice infinite times. For test scores it would probably be frequentist based on observations - my university actually give that kind of data - though a lot of students have a hunch about how hard a test is going to be.)

The student case can change to asking "What is the probability that Mike will get 50 on some random test?" but then your data (or subjective beliefs) should be about Mike. Eventually you can take the data of all test taken by any student and construct the distribution governing the probability of getting score Y on **a test**.

Comment: Right, but why can we say the probability of rolling a 2 on a dye is (1/6)? But at the same time we cant say the probability of a student scoring a 75 on a test is (x) because we don't know what the probability distribution function is. So their definition of P assumes that $N_j$ somehow includes the PDF.

Comment: Its the matter of time. You can not know what the distribution of results for a test which was not yet taken by anyone. When you have the test scroes than you can construct the distribution, and then whenever you draw a sample you are asking **when i take a random test from the pile of tests, what is the probability that the grade will be so and so**, you are NOT asking **what is the probability of some unrelated student to get such a grade?**, because that depends on his abilities, his studying efforts, the guy who grades the test and so on.

Comment: a matter of "repetition" is maybe the right word.